# Google Charts API into data.medicare.gov

Tags: socrata, soda

We are trying to interconnect the data.medicare.gov data and have it displayed into various google charts. We would like to have a pulldown type of data selector which then allows us to choose the record, and then have the stats displayed on the various google charts.

Does anyone know of a page that shows the examples of google charts which are connected to the data.medicare.gov ?

Here are a few examples of the pages that we created, and would like to interconnect with the data on the data.medicare.gov

http://u19124280.onlinehome-server.com/keacare/health_survery_dificiencies/

We have an example of this using the socrata visualizer, but we were't sure on how to customize the look of this version, so we would like to modify the pages above with the google charts to interconnect with the data from data.medicare.gov.

This is the example of it using the socrata visualizer:
http://u19124280.onlinehome-server.com/keacare/api_tests/health_survery_dificiencies/

Thank you for your feedback,

Kcare

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to post your question as clearly as you can and try and explain the specfic problem you are having. And show code you have tried to solve this problem. Please look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As a starting example, [take a look at this blog post by Socrata](https://dev.socrata.com/blog/2017/01/03/gauge-visualizations-using-the-google-charts-library.html) on examples using Socrata API with Socrata. It's not specific to the Medicaid data, but could be helpful.